# Ionic: App crashes on emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crash

My Ionic app randomly crashes on an emulator with `Android 4.3.1`, works fine on a real device with `6.0.1`

These are my logs of 3 different crashes, any idea?

```
E/chromium(10153): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
W/cr_BindingManager(10153): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 10153
I/chromium(10153): [INFO:CONSOLE(26836)] "[native transition] $stateChangeStart", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (26836)
I/chromium(10153): [INFO:CONSOLE(26836)] "[native transition]", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (26836)
D/dalvikvm(10153): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1765K, 56% free 3184K/7092K, paused 3ms, total 21ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(10153): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.645MB for 1463052-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(10153): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 23K, 36% free 4590K/7092K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
D/dalvikvm(10153): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 36% free 4589K/7092K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 3ms
E/chromium(10153): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
E/chromium(10153): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2134)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0xba08fef0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
E/chromium(10153): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
D/cr_Ime  (10153): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime  (10153): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
E/chromium(10153): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()
D/cr_Ime  (10153): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime  (10153): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
W/CordovaPlugin(10153): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Keyboard1454373881
W/CordovaPlugin(10153): Result was: "Invalid action"
W/CordovaPlugin(10153): Attempted to send a second callback for ID: Keyboard1454373882
W/CordovaPlugin(10153): Result was: "Invalid action"
```

---

```
E/chromium( 9239): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2134)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0xba08f0a0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
I/InputDispatcher( 1211): Application is not responding: Window{b3ce6030 u0 com.ionicframework.myapp/com.ionicframework.myapp.MainActivity}.  It has been 5006.1ms since event, 5005.5ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.
I/WindowManager( 1211): Input event dispatching timed out sending to com.ionicframework.myapp/com.ionicframework.myapp.MainActivity
I/Process ( 1211): Sending signal. PID: 9239 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 9239): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/Process ( 1211): Sending signal. PID: 1211 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 1211): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 1211): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process ( 1211): Sending signal. PID: 1269 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 1269): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 1269): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/Process ( 1211): Sending signal. PID: 1369 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm( 1369): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm( 1369): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm( 1211): GC_CONCURRENT freed 855K, 36% free 6799K/10484K, paused 5ms+1ms, total 36ms
D/dalvikvm( 1211): GC_EXPLICIT freed 103K, 35% free 6818K/10484K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 9ms
W/dalvikvm( 9239): threadid=3: spin on suspend #1 threadid=2 (pcf=0)
E/ActivityManager( 1211): ANR in com.ionicframework.sozapp356272 (com.ionicframework.sozapp356272/.MainActivity)
E/ActivityManager( 1211): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
E/ActivityManager( 1211): Load: 0.9 / 0.66 / 0.46
E/ActivityManager( 1211): CPU usage from 13624ms to 0ms ago:
E/ActivityManager( 1211):   99% 9239/com.ionicframework.sozapp356272: 99% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
E/ActivityManager( 1211):   0% 810/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3 minor
E/ActivityManager( 1211): 100% TOTAL: 99% user + 0% kernel + 0% irq
E/ActivityManager( 1211): CPU usage from 881ms to 1416ms later:
E/ActivityManager( 1211):   96% 9239/com.ionicframework.sozapp356272: 96% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager( 1211):     96% 9244/GC: 96% user + 0% kernel
E/ActivityManager( 1211):   3.7% 1211/system_server: 0% user + 3.7% kernel
E/ActivityManager( 1211):     1.8% 1228/ActivityManager: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
E/ActivityManager( 1211): 100% TOTAL: 96% user + 3.7% kernel
W/dalvikvm( 9239) : threadid=3: spin on suspend #2 threadid=2 (pcf=0)
```

---

```
E/chromium( 7116): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2134)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0xba0a1ba0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
D/dalvikvm( 1211): GC_CONCURRENT freed 752K, 33% free 5936K/8788K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 8ms
E/chromium( 7116): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2134)] [.CommandBufferContext.RenderWorker-0xba0a1ba0]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GLES2DecoderImpl::DoBindTexImage2DCHROMIUM: <- error from previous GL command
F/libc    ( 7116): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000074 (code=1), thread 7116 (rk.sozapp356272)
F/libc    ( 7116): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000018 (code=1), thread 7179 (Chrome_InProcGp)
F/libc    ( 7116): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 7159 (Chrome_IOThread)
I/DEBUG   (  794): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  794): Build fingerprint: 'generic_x86/sdk_x86/generic_x86:4.3.1/JB_MR2/1743067:eng/test-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  794): Revision: '0'
I/DEBUG   (  794): pid: 7116, tid: 7116, name: UNKNOWN  >>> com.ionicframework.sozapp356272 <<<
I/DEBUG   (  794): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000074
I/DEBUG   (  794):     eax 00000000  ebx 00000020  ecx b3e95eb8  edx 00000018
I/DEBUG   (  794):     esi b0f60bf8  edi b2bd8d94
I/DEBUG   (  794):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
I/DEBUG   (  794):     eip b6b9675c  ebp bfca6ca8  esp bfca6c30  flags 00010286
I/DEBUG   (  794): 
I/DEBUG   (  794): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #00  pc 0002d75c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #01  pc 0000a1bf  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #02  pc 0003af12  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+66)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #03  pc 000365d9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+217)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #04  pc 000ba887  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, char*)+759)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #05  pc 00080ee1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+145)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #06  pc 0005bc92  /system/lib/libdvm.so (Check_CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*)+242)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #07  pc 0006241a  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+42)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #08  pc 000965e1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeDisplayEventReceiver::handleEvent(int, int, void*)+193)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #09  pc 00027dba  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+890)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #10  pc 00028123  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+51)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #11  pc 000ac171  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, int, int)+81)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #12  pc 00029c5b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+79)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #13  pc 00006b3f  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #14  pc 00085621  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+273)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #15  pc 0004b782  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+66)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #16  pc 00172518  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #17  pc 00005e17  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #18  pc 0003af12  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+66)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #19  pc 000365d9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+217)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #20  pc 000b9af2  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+1634)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #21  pc 000ce490  /system/lib/libdvm.so (Dalvik_java_lang_reflect_Method_invokeNative(unsigned int const*, JValue*)+288)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #22  pc 00172518  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #23  pc 00005eff  <unknown>
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #24  pc 0003af12  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+66)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #25  pc 000365d9  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+217)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #26  pc 000ba887  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, char*)+759)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #27  pc 0007708d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+109)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #28  pc 00053655  /system/lib/libdvm.so (Check_CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*)+309)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #29  pc 0005d0fa  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+42)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #30  pc 0005e7bc  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+924)
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #31  pc 00001017  /system/bin/app_process (main+567)
I/DEBUG   (  794): 
I/DEBUG   (  794): stack:
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6bf0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6bf4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6bf8  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6bfc  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c00  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c04  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c08  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c0c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c10  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c14  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c18  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c1c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c20  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c24  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c28  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6c2c  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #00  bfca6c30  b9d4d1c0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  794):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  794):          ........  ........
I/DEBUG   (  794):     #02  bfca6cb0  b9d4d1c0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6cb4  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6cb8  b7ec8619  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_lock+9)
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6cbc  b6b9a6b5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (IndirectRefTable::get(void*) const+37)
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6cc0  00000000  
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6cc4  b6d29cc8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6cc8  b9d4d1c0  [heap]
I/DEBUG   (  794):          bfca6ccc  b6b9f5da  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+218)
W/ActivityManager( 1211):   Force finishing activity com.ionicframework.sozapp356272/.MainActivity
D/        ( 1211): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xba23c480, tid 7533
D/Zygote  (  797): Process 7116 terminated by signal (11)
I/DEBUG   (  794): tid 7179 does not exist in pid 7116. ignoring debug request
```